# Implementing Spring Security Authorization with Group Ownership Model

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm working on an application that uses a group model to assign ownership of domain objects. I am looking for help in determining suitability of Spring Security for doing authorization.

Group Model:

The system has groups. A group is a collection of users who have some sort of authorization to do things in that group. For example, user "Sally" may be member of group "Group A" and have the "DATA_EDITING" role in that group.

Data that is entered into the system is assigned to a group, and the user-members of that group "own" that data and can operate on it according to their Role in the group. So, for example, user "Sally" above can edit (CRUD) all data assigned to "Group A".

In other words, each domain object is assigned to a "group", and each group has one or more members (users) with one or more roles.

This means that an individual domain object is "owned" by 1 or more "principal", but only transitively via the domain object's and the principal's shared group.

My Current Research:

In reading Spring Docs, it appears that the most suitable feature of Spring Security for this model is Spring ACLs. My understanding is that I could create user/principal based ACLs (in DAOS) that use my "groups" in such a way that Spring Security really has no idea about our group model, but from our user's perspective nothing would change. In other words, "Sally" above would still be able to "think" in groups, but at the database level authorization would still be done with a user/principal based ACL. A domain object's DAO would translate Sally's group membership into a standard ACL for that domain object.

It this approach feasible, or is there a better approach (which preserves the group model) using Spring Security or some other product?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security *does* to some extent support groups.

Authorities are in the typical case roles like `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`, but can also be group membership like `GROUP_A`. Basically you can populate the `Authentication` object with what you want during authentication.

An ACL entry is attached to a *security identity* (sid for short). A security identity can be either a principal (single user) *or* an authority. In your case it sounds like you want to use the later to apply an ACL rule to a group.

So yes, you can control access on group level in Spring Security.